# React get text from file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, typescript

I am having trouble with my fetch function and the usage. I am able to get my data from the data state but its returning a full string instead of an array that I can map. I have been playing around with it for a few hours and cant get my head wrapped around it.

```js
import react, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Carousel } from "@mantine/carousel";

var PATH = "/Quests/questlist.txt";

    function App() {
       const [data, setData] = useState<any>(null);
       let newData = [""];

       useEffect(() => {
        getText();
       }, []);

       async function getText() {
        fetch(`${PATH}`)
            .then((response) => response.text())
            .then((text) => {
                setData(text.split(","));
            });
        newData = data;
        console.log(data);
        }
       return (
           <div>
               <Carousel
                  className="App"
                  maw={320}
                  mx="auto"
                  withIndicators
                 `your text`height={200}
            >
                
                    
                      {newData.map((sm) => {
                            return <Carousel.Slide>{sm}</Carousel.Slide>;
                       })}
                  </Carousel>
              </div>
           );
       }

export default App;
```

To be able to map my array with the carousel components
some questlist.txt text {
Aftermath,
All Fired Up,
Alpha vs Omega,
Ancient Awakening,
Animal Magnetism,
Another Slice of H.A.M.,
As a First Resort,
Azzanadra's Quest,
Back to my Roots,
Back to the Freezer,
Battle of the Monolith,
Beneath Cursed Tides,
Between a Rock...,
Big Chompy Bird Hunting
}

Comment: Can you paste some of the contents of `questlist.txt`? How to parse that depends on its format.

Comment: @RossAllen I updated the post with sample text from the file. I am using the split() method to give me 258 array objects.

Comment: Initialize the `data` state with an empty array (`[]`) instead of `null`. Don't use `newData` at all — just remove it and all references to it.

Comment: yeah thats what I thought too but keep getting a type error within the mapping process

Comment: [Solved]
I took jsej advice again and got a type error found out within the mapping function I could declare sm to be either null or undefined so I went with that route.

Comment: Also, just in case, `newData` is totally getting in the way here. You ought to be mapping over `data`, _not_ `newData`. `newData` is not providing any value on top of `data` - and worse - it is not stateful so React won't necessarily use it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here:
From what I can see, you presume that the promise from the fetch call is not asynchronous. And the second issue is that useState is not set immediatly when calling `setData`.

When you call fetch.then() it does not run immediatly. It continues execution in your example continues to the line `newData = data;`. And when it resolves the file it will execute the callback. So when you are setting the newData it is setting the initial value of data which is `null`.

Also if it would for some reason immediatly execute the callback and setData and after that the `newData = data;` it would still not work as react does not immediatly set the state when calling setData. Only on the next render it has updated the state.

It was already suggested to drop the `newData` variable which is a good idea to me. Here is an updated version of your getText function:

```
async function getText(): Promise<void> {
    const result: string = await (await fetch(PATH)).text();
    const splitResult: string[] = result.split(',');
    setData(splitResult);
}
```

Also using `async` for your function and not using `await` does not really do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I really appreciate everyone's input I am happy to say I have figured it out. I do have other problems but I would rather solve them myself. This fetch function just wasnt sitting right with me because I knew it was correct I was just missing a type.

```
const [questList, setQuestList] = useState<string[]>([]);
const fetchQuestList = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(QUEST_FILE_PATH);
        const text = await response.text();
        const quests = text.split(",");
        setQuestList(quests);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching quest list:", error);
    }
};
```

This was my final result. I appreciate you guys! First great interaction with the community!